# how to Disable fields selection by mouse in selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have developed a very simple portal login application in selenium. It works perfectly, with following code

```
WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
driver.get("http://inernalportal.com");
WebElement element = null;
element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtLoginID"));
element.sendKeys("user");
element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtpassID"));
element.sendKeys("password");
element = driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
element.click();
```

However I am facing an issue when selenium enters username and in between entering the password if user selects username field explicitly by clicking on that field (using mouse) then selenium enters password at txtLoginID instead of at txtpassID and which will be visible to the userasd.

I Want to disable mouse/keyboard events during data entry.

How to do this. PLease guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, this will disable mouse events

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;


    WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://inernalportal.com");
    WebElement element = null;
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtLoginID"));
    element.sendKeys("user");
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('txtLoginID').style.pointerEvents='none'", driver.findElement(By.id("txtLoginID")));
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("txtpassID"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('txtpassID').style.pointerEvents='none'", driver.findElement(By.id("txtpassID")));
    element.sendKeys("password");
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
    element.click();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I really appreciate your timely help.

Comment: Girish, your tricks works very well with firefox, however didnt worked with IE. I am using IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0. My code is same only difference is <br> System.setProperty( "webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

Comment: May be Java script is not executing correctly in IE. Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsById('txtLoginID').value = 'id';");
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsById('txtPassword').value = 'pass';"); solved my issue. Thanks